# Unable to unbind .modal.data-api events

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery

I have been trying to work out how to remove the data-api from modal dialogs when using Twitter Bootstrap. I am using the current build (version 2.3.2) and have attempted all of the following:

Just removing the modal data api on both `body` (as documented) and `document` (as that is where the events actually appear to be bound), still the event occurs.

```
$("body").off(".modal.data-api");

$(document).off(".modal.data-api");
```

Then I thought I would try removing the whole data api (on both body and document), but neither worked again.

```
$("body").off(".data-api");

$(document).off(".data-api");
```

Additionally I have tried specifying the selector `[data-toggle="modal"]` on each of the above, but to no avail.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

#### UPDATE

It appears to be because in https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js the events are bound wrapped in a function that is passed into jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).off('click.modal').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function ( e ) {
        var $this = $(this),
            href = $this.attr('href'),
            $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))), //strip for ie7
            option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote: !/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data());

        e.preventDefault();
        $target
            .modal(option)
            .one('hide', function () {
                $this.focus();
            })
    });
});
```

If I remove the `$(function () {` and corresponding `});` then it is possible to unbind the events. So, the question now is, why is it not possible to unbind these events whilst that wrapper is there?

### Resolution

I hadn't recognised the `$(function() { ... });` as a shorthand for `$(document).ready`, especially when it isn't even necessary for `.off` and `.on`. So, until the plugin removes that bit of code, I have found that the following will do the job:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).off(".modal.data-api");
});
```

Comment: It appears to be related to the fact I am using https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal as a patch to get responsive modals. Removing this plugin shows that I can unbind the events. However, I don't understand why I cannot unbind the events from this plugin.